# How to prove that the two line segments are equal, if possible

Tags: geometry

There are two triangles. The first triangle has 3 vertices called ABC, while the second one has DEF. If vertex A = vertex D, vertex B = vertex E, and vertex C = vertex F.
Is there any way that I can prove that line segment AB is equal to line segment DE?

I apologize in advance if the problem is incomprehensible, I just do not really know how to describe the problem that I am facing currently.
[kinda a representation of the triangle given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuK0C.png)

Comment: What do you mean by **vertex $A$=vertex $B$** and so on$??$

Comment: The point or vertex A on the first triangle is equal to the vertex D on the second triangle. I was wondering if those points are equal, then the line segments created using those points are also equal.

Comment: You're saying that two points are equal (apparently dimensionally). But that can't be true, as points don't have dimensions. The points can only superimpose themselves on each other.

Comment: Write the full question.

Comment: I added the triangle picture, I hope it will help visualize the problem more clearly, as my wordings are kind of bad.

Comment: You say the triangles are "equal in size" in the picture. That seems to be what you want to prove. If all you know is that the angles match then the triangles are not equal in size.

Comment: Can it not be proved using SSS? I thought that if two points are equal, then the resulting line segments are also equal. For example, if B = C and C = F, then BC = EF, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In your image, you say that both triangles are equal in size. Then it follows that $AB=DE$.

Also, $SSS$ is side-side-side criterion, which means that the two triangles are congruent if all of their corresponding sides are equal. So, if you're using $SSS$ then you actually already had $AB=DE$. So you can't use this either.

The criterion that can be used here is $SAS$. If in your triangle it is given that $AC=DF$ and $BC=EF$ and $\angle ACB=\angle DFE$ then by **corresponding parts of congruent triangles** you can say that $AB=DE$.